# Does CreateDirectory apply DirectorySecurity on pre-existing directory?

Tags: c#, .net, create-directory

For `CreateDirectory` API ( in particular the managed one): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String, DirectorySecurity)
```

If the directory exists, does this call also update the DirectorySecurity?

Or does it silently ignore since the creation failed. Documentation doesn't mention that. It only says: [**"This object is returned regardless of whether a directory at the specified path already exists."**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can check:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ba5a33a58548f8bff03f792487bee0a89b3b3125/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Win32FileSystem.cs
Method start at line 62.

Comment: No it doesn't. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't change the instance of `DirectorySecurity` in any way.
You can check it for yourself [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,e3885fef9f6af9de).

Comment: thank for sharing the code. It took me long time to find it internally. Had no idea we open-sourced that...